# dictionary that executes function when the key is accessed

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a way to achieve the following:
A dictionary that returns the current datetime when the key is accessed. (So NOT the datetime of when the key was stored)

Example that does not do what i want:

```
d = {'key': datetime.datetime.now()}
d['key'] # returns datetime of dic creation instead of current
```

As my dictionary key will be accessed by existing code outside of my control, i am unable to do things like `d['key']()`.
I was hoping of something similar to the `@property` decorator for classes, which executes a function when accessed

Comment: Does the existing code check the type of dictionary? If not, you can customize a class and overload `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your thing a subclass of dict you can intercept the `__getitem__` method:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        val = super().__getitem__(item)
        if callable(val):
            return val()
        else:
            return val

def func():
    return "ran function"

d = MyDict(a=1, f=func)

print(d["a"])
print(d["f"])
```

outputs:

```
1
ran function
```